# Пересечение цилиндра и прямоугольно параллелепипеда (куба в частном случае)

Tags: геометрия, 3d

Бокс задан двумя точками Bmax(X_max, Y_max, Z_max) и Bmin(X_min, Y_min, Z_min).
По этим двум точкам можно определить остальные 6 вершин бокса, например: (X_max, Y_max, Z_min), (X_max, Y_min, Z_max) и так далее...

Цилиндр задан двумя центрами его оснований O1(x1,y1,z1), O2(x2,y2,z2) и радиусом R.

Т.е. цилиндр может находиться под разными углами, необязательно в строго вертикальном положении, а куб всегда строго выровнен по осям.

Моя задача, определить пересекается ли цилиндр с кубом.

Сперва я хотел реализовать следующий алгоритм:

1. Определить если хотя бы один конец находится внутри бокса, то значит пересекается
2. Если оба конца за пределами бокса, то для каждой грани куба найти уравнение плоскости, и проверить пересекается ли плоскость с цилиндром
   Но так и не нашей способ  проверить пересекается ли плоскость с цилиндром, да и не уверен что это правильный алгоритм проверки.

Далее я нашел документ в котором описан другой алгоритм:
https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/IntersectionBoxCylinder.pdf

и его исходный код: https://www.geometrictools.com/Downloads/Downloads.html файл - (GTEngine 7.0 Distribution (ZIP))

Начал тестировать алгоритм, но результат не  соответствует ожидаемому результату.

Как тестировал:

1. Распаковал архив
2. Открыл решение GeometricTools\GTE\Samples\Intersection\IntersectBoxCylinder\IntersectBoxCylinderDX11.v16.sln
3. Запустил отладку рендерится сцена:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разобравшись в IntersectBoxCylinderWindow3.cpp понял что когда бокс пересекает цилиндр то он становится красным метод TestIntersection().
Там же можно поменять начальные координаты и размеры фигур (бокса и цилиндра) в методе CreateScene()

Установил для бокса параметры :

```
    mCylinder.axis.origin = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.5f }; // основание цилиндра
    mCylinder.axis.direction = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };// направление (можно вычислить если знаем координаты конца и начала)
    mCylinder.radius = 1.0f; // радиус
    mCylinder.height = 1.0f; // высота
    
    mBox.center = { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f }; // центр 
    mBox.axis[0] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f }; // угол поворота бокса (в моем случае никогда не изменяется)
    mBox.axis[1] = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f }; 
    mBox.axis[2] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    mBox.extent = { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f }; // Эксцент
```

Отлаживаем видим, что никакого пересечения нет, но алгоритм его фиксирует и делает бокс красным

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. тоже самое проверил написав следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Mathematics/IntrAlignedBox3Cylinder3.h"
#include "Mathematics/Cylinder3.h"
#include "Mathematics/Vector3.h"
#include "Mathematics/Vector.h"
#include "Mathematics/AlignedBox.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <limits.h>
#include <float.h>

// расстояние между точками в пространстве 
static double PointPointDistance(Vector3<double> const& point1, Vector3<double> const& point2)
{
    return sqrt(pow(point1[0] - point2[0], 2) + pow(point1[1] - point2[1], 2) + pow(point1[2] - point2[2], 2));
}

int32_t main()
{
    // центры оснований
    Vector3<double> start = {0,0,1.5};
    Vector3<double> end = {0,0,2.5};
    // высота цилиндра
    double height = PointPointDistance(start, end);
    // направление цилиндра
    Vector3<double> dir = end - start;
    Normalize(dir);
    Cylinder3<double> cylinder;
    cylinder.axis.direction = dir;
    cylinder.axis.origin = start;
    cylinder.radius = 1;
    cylinder.height = height;
   
    AlignedBox3<double> box;
    // минимальная/максимальная вершина
    box.min = { 0,0,0 };
    box.max = { 1,1,1 };

    // хит тест
    TIQuery<double, AlignedBox3<double>, Cylinder3<double>> mQuery;
    bool result = mQuery(box,cylinder).intersect;

    return 0;
}
```

результат тоже true, хотя по факту это не так

Помимо этого, не проходят еще несколько тестов

Других библиотек с реализацией не нашел, и так не смог реализовать алгоритм самостоятельно.

Поделитесь методом, если знаете

Comment: Заметьте, что у Эберли цилиндр, по крайней мере, в pdf, определён через центр оси, а у вас используется центр одного из оснований.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действительно цилиндр нужно определять через центр оси, а не через центр основания.
Вот тут пример с правильным применением модуля
https://github.com/SebWouters/AabbCyl/tree/main